# Правильно ли я профетчил результат?

Tags: ооп, mysqli, php

Пока учусь, так что строго не судите:

```
public function getUserNameByEmail($usE)
{
    if ($result = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `email`=? LIMIT 1'));
    {
        $result->bind_param("s",$usE);
        $result->execute();
        $result->bind_result($name);
        $result->fetch();
        $result->close();
    }

        return $name;
}
```

В принципе, это работает, жалоб нет, но таких функций мне с десяток сейчас надо написать, перестраховываюсь. В общем плане мне нужно выбрать 1-но значение исходя из другого. Просто в туториале, по которому я делаю, не сказано, как это делается. Надеюсь с пониманием отнесетесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос касается конкретно этой функции, то вполне правильно.
Можно еще буферизацию сделать:

```
$result->bind_param("s",$usE);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($name);
$result->store_result() // буферизация, если необходимо
$result->fetch();
$result->close();
```